# ObservableCollection<T> does not update ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox, observablecollection

I've set the `ItemsSource` of a `ListBox` to an `ObservableCollection<Employee>` collection, and my `Employee` class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

On the `Employee`, I've bound several properties, one of them a `Color` property, and I've ensured that it invokes the `PropertyChanged` event when it's changed. I've also checked with the debugger that the `PropertyChanged` invoke is called.

However, when databound the `Background` of the `ListBoxItem` in the bound `ListBox` does **never update**, which is extremely fustrating.

Setting the `ItemsSource` to null, and resetting it after works, but it's not how we're meant to utilize the Observer Pattern.

The XAML used:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}"
                         Color="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColor}" />
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="{Binding Path=Color, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}" />
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,1,0,1" />
    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="HelperList_MouseDoubleClick" />
</Style>

<ListBox x:Name="helperList" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" 
         Margin="5,2,0,5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
         SelectionChanged="HelperList_SelectionChanged">
</ListBox>
```

More code in response to first reply:

```
public class Employee : Person
{
    private EmployeeColor color = new EmployeeColor();
    public EmployeeColor Color
    {
        get { return this.color; }
        set
        {
            if(!this.color.Equals(value))
                OnPropertyChanged("Color");

            this.color = value;
        }
    }
}

var employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
//... fill out data here    
helperList.ItemsSource = employees;
```

Comment: Nothing wrong here, can you provide more code? Employer class and how do you set ItemSource ?

Comment: done, check the updated code. Even it should be fairly obvious, as I said, I just set the ItemSource property to a ObserverableCollection!

Comment: What is in your ColorConverter? Is it converting a Color into a Brush as expected by the Background property? I suspect the problem is there.

Comment: It doesn't work any other property either as well. And yes, it's converting just fine.

As I said earlier, setting the ItemSource to null, and then to the same ObserveableCollection<T> afterwards, makes it work. It's however, not how it should be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.

OnPropertyChanged was called BEFORE the actual value of the property was set, so the UI was updating accordingly to the old value.

Solution: Call OnPropertyChanged *after* setting the property value.

Comment: sounds logical. :) Property is onlyu changed after you've set the value. :)
There also exists a INotifyPropertyChanging interface ...